# Char length exceeds DDL length

Tags: amazon-web-services, char, amazon-redshift

I am attempting to copy data into redshift from an S3 bucket, however I am getting a 1204 error code 'char length exceeds DDL length'.

```
copy table_name from '[data source]'
access_key_id '[access key]'
secret_access_key '[secret access key]'
region 'us-east-1'
null as 'NA'
delimiter ','
removequotes;
```

The error occurs in the very first row, where it tries to put the state abbreviation 'GA' into the data_state column which is defined with the data type char(2).  When I query the stl_load_errors table I get the following result:

```
line_number  colname      col_length  type   raw_field_value  err_code  err_reason
1            data_state   2           char   GA               1204      Char length exceeds DDL length
```

As far as I can tell that shouldn't exceed the length as it is two characters and it is set to char(2).  Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by changing the data type to char(3) instead, however still not sure why char(2) wouldn't work

Comment: See if any of your records has `space` or `\t` etc in your data

Comment: @RedBoy I checked but did not find anything like that in my data set

Answer (score 0):

Mine did this as well, for a state column too. Redshift defaults char to char(1) - so I had to specify char(2) - are you sure it didn't default back to char(1) because mine did

Comment: It looks like your answer got cutoff halfway through?

Answer (score 0):

Open the file up with a Hex editor, or use an online one [here](https://www.onlinehexeditor.com/), and look at the `GA` value in the `data_state` column.

If it has three dots before it like so:

`...GA`

Then the file (or when it was orignally created) was `UTF-8-BOM` not just `UTF-8`.

You can open the file in something like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and go to `Encoding` in the top bar then select `Convert to UTF-8`.